# Estrutura de um banco de dados para 'Amigo Secreto'

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou a criar uma sistema de amigo secreto para à familia, onde será possível ter:

- Cadastro de usuários com seus determinado Dados *(ex: Tamanho do tênis, camisa, etc...)* ;
- Grupos de usuários cadastrados;
- Gerar um sorteio com os usuários inseridos nesse determinado grupo;
- Lista de Desejos;
- Um mural no grupo, para deixar as mensagens *(Anônimas ou não)*;
- Notificações *(caso haja alguma mensagem inserida no grupo, pedidos de amizade, etc...);*
- Sistema de relacionamento *(Amigos)*.

## O que já foi feito:

```
 TB_USUARIO |   TB_PERFIL   |   TB_GRUPO    |   TB_RELACIONAMENTO       |   TB_MENSAGEM_GRUPO   |   TB_DESEJO               
------------|---------------|---------------|---------------------------|---------------------- |-----------------
ID_USUARIO  |   ID_PERFIL   |   ID_GRUPO    |   ID_RELACIONAMENTO       |   ID_MENSAGEM_GRUPO   |   ID_DESEJO
ID_PERFIL   |   NOME        |   ID_USUARIO  |   ID_USUARIO_SOLICITOU    |   ID_GRUPO            |   ID_USUARIO
USUARIO     |   SOBRENOME   |               |   (usuário que solicitou) |   ID_USUARIO          |   DESEJO
SENHA       |   EMAIL       |               |   ID_USUARIO_RECEBEU      |   MENSAGEM            |
                                            |   (usuário que recebeu)   |   DATA_HORA           |
```

Minha maior dúvida é em relação ao `Grupo de Usuários`, `Notificações` e sobre `Gerar um sorteio com os usuários inseridos em um determinado grupo`. Qual a melhor maneira de Estruturar o Banco de Dados, e qual a lógica*(em php)* que posso usar para realizar o sorteio?

Comment: Já pensas-te em alguma coisa?

Comment: Sim, @CesarMiguel, Atualizei minha pergunta.

Comment: Bem melhor e já apresenta algum esforço, vou retirar o meu voto para fechar a pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diversos modos e maneiras, depende de quem está modelando o sistema.

Vamos supor a tabela do grupo:

`TB_GRUPO`

- `ID_GRUPO` (identificador);
- `NOME_GRUPO` (nome, amigo oculto empresa xyz);
- `DATA_SORTEIO` (que será automatico pelo sistema);
- `DATA_ENTREGA` (seria a data da troca dos presentes);
- `LOCAL_ENTREGA` (seria o local da troca dos presentes);
- `VALOR_MIN` (seria o valor mínimo do presente, se não tiver `min` ele fica como `null` por exemplo)
- `VALOR_MAX` (seria o valor máximo do presente, mesma ideia do mínimo)
- `STATUS` (indicaria se já foi sorteado ou não. o sorteio deveria acontecer automaticamente na data indicada, ou, se o admin quiser antes, acionando um botão por exemplo, e esse 'flag' indicaria que já foi sorteado)

Um grupo poderia ter um ou mais administradores

`TB_ADMS_GRUPO`

- `ID` (auto incrementavel, só pra indexar)
- `ID_GRUPO`
- `ID_USUARIO`

Um grupo poderia ter vários participantes

`TB_MEMBROS_GRUPO`

- `ID` (auto incrementavel, só pra indexar)
- `ID_GRUPO`
- `ID_USUARIO`
- `ID_AMIGO` (iniciaria como `null`, ao ocorrer o sorteio seria preenchido com o `id_usuario` do amigo sorteado)

Na hora do sorteio, você iria selecionar todos os membros e preencher a coluna amigo de todos. Tome cuidado no algoritmo de sorteio. O ideal é que seja cíclico, ou seja o primeiro a dar o presente sempre seja o último para não quebrar a roda de entrega.
Não sortear a própria pessoa pra ela mesma (básico).

Para a notificação, basta enviar um email para o email do usuário no momento da ação que deve ser notificada. Não precisa necessariamente de um registro para a notificação.

Você pode até registrar a notificação, mas na minha opinião é desnecessário, afinal se você notifica um usuário que ele recebeu uma nova mensagem, a mensagem vai estar registrada. Se ele recebe um email informando essa notificação, é o suficiente pra ele ir no sistema e verificar a mensagem que ESTÁ REGISTRADA. Já a notificação, se registrada, pra que serviria?

Veja exemplos, navegue em sites de amigo secreto e veja como eles funcionam, isso vai ajudá-lo. Um muito bom para fazer a brincadeira é o http://www.amigosecreto.com.br.